# Поворот объекта (изображения) в сторону следующей координаты перемещения

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, angular, angular5

Хай, уважаемые коллеги. Разрабатываем на данный момент некие летающие объекты по экрану на Angular, возникла проблема - рандомно они летают, но без поворотов, уже перепробовали множество вариантов, но объекты так и не поворачивают в сторону следующей координаты. Прошу помощи, буду очень благодарен.

Есть два вида рандомного перемещения - их прилагаю ссылками:

[(codesandbox - не реклама) Сам проект - объекты и движения app/fly](https://codesandbox.io/s/1yn1n2xq3j)

[(codesandbox - не реклама) Всё тот же проект, но с другим рандомом (так же app/fly)](https://codesandbox.io/s/x2kmryz4q)

Буду очень признателен за помощь, там уже есть rotate в стилях, но он лишь был тестовый и с некоторых вариантов остался там (уж не судите за косяки) :с

Comment: `directionVector = (nextCoordinate - currentCoordinate).normalize`

Comment: @MBo А можно ли как-то на примере моего кода показать? Конечно, я благодарен за ответ, хоть что-то уже :)

Comment: @MBo хоть малейшую часть какую-то, чтобы знать куда дальше копать

Comment: Я вообще не вижу, где там у Вас код. В псевдокоде могу показать, как найти вектор направления или угол, но мне нужно понимать, какие данные имеются

Comment: @MBo app/fly/fly.component или о каком коде речь?

Comment: Видимо, да. Написал ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть текущие координаты  объекта `x,y`, а цели - `tx, ty`
Тогда вектор направления

```
dx = tx - x
dy = ty - y
```

Нормализуем его для получения единичной длины

```
len = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
udx = dx / len
udy = dy / len
```

Вот эти компоненты единичного вектора есть заодно косинус и синус угла направления, если он вдруг понадобится

```
dirAngle = atan2(udy, udx)
```

Чтобы двигать  объект в заданном направлении со скоростью V, нужно обновлять координаты (как это делается в методе `applyDeltaX`)  (если интервалы обновления меняются, это надо тоже учитывать)

```
x = x + V * udx 
y = y + V * udy
```